# Horizontal scroll issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, horizontal-scrolling

I finished coding [this website](http://decoded.ro/bbb/) using bootstrap and now I have this issue regarding that horizontal scroll which was not supposed to happen. This is my first website using boostrap.

I tried using 'divide et impera' by removing snippets of code in order to find the issue. The horizontal scroll disappeared when I removed pretty much the entire content / website so I suppose it is related to the main container ?

I can't seem to figure out the problem, been banging by head against the wall for the past few hours.

Comment: No horizontal scroll bar for me in Google Chrome on Windows.

Comment: I dont see an horizontal scrollbar too

Comment: looks like it happens on mobile guys

Comment: Neither do i (fedora 22 with chrome 46.0.2490.86). if you see some div with horizontal scroll that you does not want it to have, just try to set the CSS style "overflow-x: hidden;".

Comment: Ok, an horizontal scroll bar is shown when the view's width is less than 768px!! Setting body,html { overflow-x: hidden; } makes the horizontal scroll bar go away!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to take anything away from @Tulio Castro, as putting `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `body` should fix this.  This is a hacky fix, however, in that it doesn't fix the problem itself, rather, it fixes a currently visible consequence of the problem.  I figured you might want to know the actual problem--why this is happening and what you can do better.

First let me say that bootstrap is a delicate system:  Every time you apply your own styles, you'll need to be checking to make sure your styles don't clash with bootstrap's.

So here are the fixes:

You can run this jQuery when the horizontal scrollbar is visible, and it will tell you which elements are causing the overflow:

```
$('*').filter(function() { return $(this).width() > $('body').width(); });
```

In your case, it will return three culprits, all of them `.row` elements:

1) The first `.row` needs to be nested in a `.col-xs-12` element.  You can't have a `.row` as an immediate child of a `.row` element in bootstrap.

2) The second `.row` has a parent with class `.partneri`.  You applied custom CSS to this parent element, which broke bootstrap.  In this case, bootstrap wanted 10px of padding on the right and left, but your CSS took this away:

```
.parteneri
{
    ....
    padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
```

Change this to

```
.parteneri
{
    ....
    padding: 10px;
}
```

And you should be fine.

3) The third `.row` has the same thing.  The parent with class `.sub-footer` breaks bootstrap's padding.  Change

```
.sub-footer
{
    border-top: 2px solid #f8f8f8;
    padding: 10px 0 4px 0;
}
```

to

```
.sub-footer
{
    border-top: 2px solid #f8f8f8;
    padding: 10px 10px 4px 10px;
}
```

And you're set.  Best of luck.

Comment: Indeed I was wondering why is this happening and what is the cause. Thanks a lot for your detailed post :)

Answer (score 1):

I saw this horizontal scroll in apple iphone 4, just solve this, just define thiss css:

```
html,body{
    overflow-x:hidden;
 }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Well, I did not thought it is going to be this simple. I was imagining something way more complicated. Thanks a lot!